# Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou obtendo este erro ao tentar fazer um *insert* no banco usando as funções Mysqli:

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Uc16\cadastro.php on line 5`

O que estou fazendo errado?

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios(user_nome,user_senha,user_nivel,user_cpf,user_end_rua,user_end_bairro,user_end_numero,user_tel,user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $sql->bind_param('ssisssiss',
        $_POST['user_nome'], 
        $_POST['user_senha'],
        $_POST['user_nivel'],
        $_POST['user_cpf'],
        $_POST['user_end_rua'],
        $_POST['user_end_bairro'],
        $_POST['user_end_numero'],
        $_POST['user_tel'],
        $_POST['user_email']);
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Registrado";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();

     ?>
```

Comment: O `bind_param` só pode ser usado num `stmt` e não numa string. Então o `$sql` deve ser um `stmt`, por exemplo um `mysqli_prepare()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não foi possível fazer um bind em uma string, ele deve ser feito na variável de conexão. Primeiramente deve-se chamar `prepare()`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios(user_nome,user_senha,user_nivel,user_cpf,user_end_rua,user_end_bairro,user_end_numero,user_tel,user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(...);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
   echo 'erro: '. $conexao->error;
}
```

Comment: mas ai da esse erro: Warning: mysqli::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Uc16\cadastro.php on line 5

Comment: @IgorOliveira no `preapre()` você deve passar a consulta, corrigi isso na resposta agora.

Comment: Funcionou mas estou tendo erro de sintax do sql, sabe oque pode ser?

Comment: @IgorOliveira precisa ver onde é a indição do inicio do erro, pode ser um nome de coluna escrito errado etc.

Comment: right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

Comment: @IgorOliveira quando vc usa o `prepare()` não chama o `query()` mas o `execute()` editei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!